# Web API 2 Receiving Json

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

Can anyone give me example of sending json data from jquery ajax to web api controller, both client and server code? For instance I want to send `{Name: "SomeName", Email: "SomeEmail"}` through ajax as post request and to get those values at controller...

Comment: Can anyone do your work for you? No, no one can do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server side to retrieve values:

```
public class RequestModel()
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

public MyWebApiController : ApiController
{
    public object Post(RequestModel model)
    {
        // Do something
        // Return same values back
        return model;
    }
}
```

Client side to post values:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: '/Api/MyWebApi',
    data: { Name = "Bob", Email = "bob@example.com" }, 
    success: function (responseData) {

         // Do something on success, with the returned data
         alert("Email:" + responseData.Email + ", Name:" + responseData.Name);

    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

         // Display error?
    }
})
```